# PowerShell DTexec /ISServer pass a connectionstring as package variable

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis, dtexec

I want to execute a SSIS package on ISServer via PowerShell. 
I used the script found on microsoft page. This doesn't work out for me. 
I want to pass a connectionstring but not to assign to the connectionmanager but just as a variable string. In the connectionstring there are  `\` and ; present and powershell sees this as a new option. I just want it to be seen as a whole string.

I've tried everything, adding `"\"` and `\""` like some websites suggested, used `instead of \, put double quotes, put ' quotes, nothing works. Always getting the error option`MyServer\MyServer`;Initial is not valid.
I can't remove`MyServer\MyServer` because connection is to that instance.

The Connectionstring is assigned via a changing variable. So variable contains `Data Source=MyServer\Myserver;Initial Catalog=SQL_MyArchive;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;`

```
dtexec /ISSERVER  "\SSISDB\Test\Test.dtsx" /SERVER "MYServer" /ENVREFERENCE 8 /Par "$Package::ConnectionSource";`""Data Source=MyServer\Myserver;Initial Catalog=SQL_MyArchive;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;"`"
```

How can i let the system see the whole connectionstring as a string? `"" and "`" does not work.

Answer (score 0):

use the following syntax to pass a connectionstring to a variable *(you missed a `\"`)*

```
/Par "$Package::ConnectionSource";\""Data Source=MyServer\Myserver;Initial Catalog=SQL_MyArchive;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;"\"
```